# Run PS1 when solution load in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget, visual-studio-2015

Prior Visual Studio 2015 and nuget 3.x, there was the possibility to have some nuget packages at the solution level. Now with nuget 3, this as been deprecated. You could find the reference of this here : https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522

This cause problem in our case since we used to have a nuget on the solution level that is loaded with a init.ps1 script when solution load. In fact now, with VS2015, it doesn't get run anymore.

My question, pretty simple, is there another way to achieve that behavior in VS2015 when opening a solution?

Comment: So you want a way to import a module when opening Visual Studio or the Package Manager Console?

Answer (score 1):

While searching for something similar I found your question and [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ea5143db-a775-4919-9918-a784e9b70b19/how-to-execute-scripts-when-opening-a-solution-file?forum=vsx) 
which appears to directly answer your question.

In short, create a powershell script (or use the one you have) to create a Nuget package, and then import that package into one of your projects. Each time the project is opened the script will get executed.